# Migration to Magento 2.2.5: Customer Unable to login and Create account from frontend

Tags: customer, migration, magento-2.2.5

On migration to magento2.2.5 from magento 1.9.1.0 
on login redirecting on same login page and on creating account also redirecting on same create account page. I have deleted generated, pub/static/frontend ,cleared cache and run all the commands. Please suggest what should I do to login and create a account ?

Comment: Are you using localhost in your url?

Comment: yes,  because it is setup on my local system

Comment: You should use local ip or custom domain name. this issue because of using localhost in URL

Comment: not working, it seems me password encryption issue unable to identify

Comment: Now you are facing same issue or different?

Comment: same issue I am facing but I checked database then I saw password_hash attribute in customer_entity table in last of value of password ::  0 which is not in fresh magento 2.2.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82403/discussion-between-twinkle-systematix-and-hariharan).

Answer (score 0):

I got one hacky solution I commented code

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            //~ $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
            //~ $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($url));
            //~ return $resultRedirect;
        //~ }
```

in `module-customer/controller/account/LoginPost.php, Create.php and CreatePost.php`